# Transferring photos from iPhone to windows computer

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, photos

I recently purchased an **iPhone 5**. I was using an android device before this. When I made the switch from android to iPhone I synced my photos from my android device onto my iPhone 5. When I synced those photos over it made duplicates of every photo and stored them in a photo album (not camera roll).

**How can I get the photos from that album on my iPhone onto my windows computer and delete the duplicates?**

I am running the **Windows 7 OS**. So far I have tried importing photos and the only photos it will import are those from camera roll.

Comment: Are you looking to run the reduplication process exclusively on iOS (where it might be hard or impossible) or on the PC where it might be doable with some software or scripting? (as you can see, the answers here are focusing on the basic transfer as opposed to the harder problem of deduplicating)

Answer (score 2):

tems in the Camera Roll or the Saved Photos album of your device can be imported to your computer, just make sure to follow the instructions provided in the "Importing photos to your computer" section of this article:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4236