# Move or transfer only all the Screenshots from iPhone iOS 9.x to Windows PC?

Tags: iphone, windows, photos, ios, file-transfer

These few links/ answers do not satisfy my question because **Screenshots folder was introduced only in iOS 9.x** as per:

http://www.theverge.com/2015/7/8/8914505/apple-ios-9-beta-photos-screenshots

**Also, I found a lot of tutorials/ sites that talk about How to Delete all Screenshots - But I'd like to Copy/ Move them before Delete.**

[The simplest way to transfer photos from an iPhone to PC selectively (not sync-all)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99343/the-simplest-way-to-transfer-photos-from-an-iphone-to-pc-selectively-not-sync-a)

[Transferring photos from iPhone to windows computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96064/transferring-photos-from-iphone-to-windows-computer)

I do not wish for other pictures to go at the moment, just tons and tons of Screen shots that I've taken over the last 2 years.

They are taking up a lot of Phone space and I want them "moved/ transferred" to the Hard Drive on my Windows PC i.e. they are deleted from the Phone disk/ memory after safely Moving/ Transfering.

- "**NOT all pictures**" and **not having to choose pictures individually**
- But entire collection of **ALL SCREENSHOTS/ Pictures** in the **Screenshots folder** that are on my iPhone as a Folder or Collection to my Windows PC.

How?

> FYI
>   **Tech Specs:**
>   iPhone 5 - iOS 9.3.1
>   iTunes 12.x
>   Windows 8.1

Comment: Can you use an app like Pushbullet on both your PC and iPhone and send them all through that?

Comment: I've been looking at lot of Apps but nothing seems to do "Screenshots" in the way I'd like. Maybe something does, but cant find a verifiable solution as yet. Can you check on the PB app that you have?

Comment: With Pushbullet, you can select all the photos in your Screenshots folder on your iPhone, tap the share button, and go to Pushbullet (once you have it setup) and you can easily send those screenshots to your PC.

Comment: @JohnRamos Does this transfer over USB or WiFi? Reliable? Hope it does not use Internet data/ cloud as I've limited data from ISP/ data cap / FUP

Comment: Pushbullet transfers over Wifi, and I've found it pretty reliable. Not sure if you'll be able to do your tranafer over USB in any other method given how poorly PCs and iPhones talk to each other.